# How to call functions from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

what I am trying to do is use a dictionary of references to functions. what I want to do is something like

```
alive = {var1: <someFunction>, var2: <someOtherFunction>};
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=var1, args=(<someArgs>))
```

I want `var1` to be a reference to a function either in the .py file or in one that is in a given location.

Does anyone have any pointers to source code, tutorials, or the like?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
alive = {'var1': <someFunction>, 'var2': <someOtherFunction>}
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=alive['var1'], args=(<someArgs>))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call that function by importing your eg.py file

```
import eg

eg.var1()
```